# What's the easiest way to display multiple locations using Google Map API with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to display over 100 locations each with detailed bubble contents (ie Company Name, Address, Phone Number, Website, Industry) on a custom Google Map. How can I fetch these locations from a MySQL database using Google Maps API 3 and PHP?

Comment: As far as I know, the Google Maps API has nothing to do with fetching them from a database. I would suggest writing an SQL query in PHP, seems about the default to fetch things from an SQL database.

Comment: I suggest looking into Fusion Tables if you are uncomfortable with writing PHP and SQL. It will allow you to update a list of locations (as a spreadsheet) and then display them on a map, without needing to write any code.

Answer (score 2):

say you have an sql database of this type:
id/lat/lon/comment

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= **your key** &sensor=true">
</script>


    $sqlprep = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

    $doselect = mysql_query($sqlprep);

    echo "<script> var locations = [";

        while ($loc = mysql_fetch_assoc($doselect)){

        echo "['" .$loc[comment] ."', " . $loc['lat'] . ", " . $loc['lon'] . "";

        }

    echo " ];</script>";
```

and then in your java:

```
<script>jQuery(window).ready(function(){


          function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( YOUR CENTER LAT,LAN HERE );
               var myOptions = {
                 center: myLatlng,
                 zoom: 15,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
               };


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()


    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),


              map: map
            });


//adding the pop up windows here:

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
            })(marker, i));


      }

  initialize() ; 


   });  </script>
```

your html should be something like:

```
<html>
<body >
<div id="map_canvas" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i might be missing some parentheses but you get the point ;)
hope it helps even 8 months later :)